# JsPerf-like site for Java?

Tags: java

I'm looking for a site like [JsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) but for `Java`. Is it possible to compile code in `applet` and then immediately run it (I guess there may be some security problems)?

Comment: Read this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858150/run-java-code-online

Comment: How about client side compilation/execution?

Comment: client side? And while JsPerf like site is great for JS when you need to quickly try something out, why dont you use an IDE for Java?

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Rextester.com](http://rextester.com/runcode) for executing java code online. Looks better than its alternate [Ideone](http://ideone.com/) in terms of interface & is also free of ads.